# How do you bulk delete records in Grails/GORM?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a table which has records that need to be periodically cleared according to a set of criteria.

I was expecting that I could use the criteria builder to just delete the records, but that fails because there is no `delete` method on criteria...

```
def c = Agency.createCriteria()
c.delete
{
    eq("agency", "XXX")  
}
```

So I thought maybe I first query for the set and then delete that...

```
def c = Agency.createCriteria()
def deletions = c
{
    eq("agency", "XXX")  
}
deletions.delete
```

This also fails for the same reason, different object.

So what is the right way to do this?  It seems excessive (perverse) that I would have to iterate through the entire result set calling `delete()` on each item.

I know I can form a query to execute directly either in HQL or SQL but that feels wrong too.  Is the criteria builder only meant for retrieval?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [User Guide about deleting objects](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#deletingObjects):

> Note that Grails does not supply a
>   deleteAll method as deleting data is
>   discouraged and can often be avoided
>   through boolean flags/logic.
>
> If you really need to batch delete
>   data you can use the executeUpdate
>   method to do batch DML statements:

```
Customer.executeUpdate("delete Customer c where c.name = :oldName", [oldName:"Fred"])
```

Comment: yes, this is how I am doing it, but it is a bit crazy that I cannot use criteria.  DELETE is a valid part of query semantics and supported by all RDBMSs and a perfectly valid thing to do, in spite of what the Hibernate/GORM authors may think.  In my case it would be very bad practice to leave the out of date records in the table.

Comment: as JesperSM references: Now Grails 2+ does have a deleteAll() on DetachedCriteria.

Comment: This works. Too bad however that it does not cascade deletion of rows in child tables. It then gives an `Integrity constraint violation`. Tested this in `2.3.7`.

Comment: We ran into the same issue as @Guus. Internally, a JDBCPreparedStatement is used to execute the update which obviously doesn't  honour Hibernate or its cascading rules for entity relationships.

Comment: @Simon I know this type of solution works, but is this efficient for the solution to delete large amount of data ? Let's say I want to delete 10K data, is this fine ?

Answer (score 50):

With Grails 2.0 you can use a detached query like this:

```
Agency.where { }.deleteAll()
```

Note that you don't get the listeners and whatnot executed, but it does execute through to the database, AND it is compatible with the mocked domain stuff, as in:

```
void testWhatever() {
    mockDomain(Agency, [])
    saveABunchOfAgencies() // saves 10 of 'em
    assert Agency.count() == 10

    Agency.where { }.deleteAll()

    assert Agency.count() == 0   // Joy!
}
```

That being said *the GORM unit test mocks have a bunch of gotchas* but are in general pretty neat.

Comment: This seems like the best for sure.  I'm using it.

Comment: Grails documentation for this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#whereQueries

Comment: Jesper, I totally agree with "the GORM unit test mocks have a bunch of gotchas". Any place they are documented in?

Comment: This solution works nicely and reliable as I have tried.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to avoid HQL I'd suggest using GORM list(), delete() and Groovy's spread operator:

```
def agencyList = Agency.createCriteria().list {
    eq("agency", "XXX")  
}
agencyList*.delete()
```

Comment: wow!  what does that stray * do?  I tried exactly this but without the * and got a compiler error...

Comment: The *. is the Groovy spread operator http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator(.) In Sbglasius' example it calls the delete() method on item in the collection that was returned.

Comment: I ran into a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when using this method...  So I stopped using the spread operator and created a while loop using the iterator as per solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816196/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-non-multithreaded-program

Comment: The problem with this is that you end up fetching that whole collection, and deleting each one of them linearly. This means the whole table goes into the heap, which is not a problem for toy models, but can be for truly bulk data.

Comment: Solved my problem too : , when we get list with uses.FindAllBy* , to deleted all users , you need to user *.delete() 
Thanks @sbglasius