# grails delete all data from table / domain class, i.e. "deleteAll"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've got a domain class, Widget, that I need to delete all instances out of -- clear it out.  After that, I will load in fresh data.  What do you suggest as a mechanism to do this?

P.S.  Note this is not at bootstrap time, but at "run-time".

Comment: This is also answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10278312/329954

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easiest way is to use HQL directly:

```
DomainClass.executeUpdate('delete from DomainClass')
```

Comment: Great, thanks, this works very fast.  (unrelated to this - any thought on why the filter isn't working for me in the filter/split lines question?  Did it work for you?)

Comment: This works in the newest versions of Grails. In 2.4.4 doesn't yet.

Comment: @ataylor What if the domain class has associations? Usually, we would want to delete all of them, not just this DomainClass

Answer (score 4):

```
DomainClass.findAll().each { it.delete() }
```

If you want to avoid any GORM gotchas, such as needing to delete the object immediately and checking to make sure it actually gets deleted, add some arguments.

```
DomainClass.findAll().each { it.delete(flush:true, failOnError:true) }
```

Comment: Note that this will load the entire collection, from the database, into memory, then delete each one, individually, with a separate database query for each one. The performance of this will be terrible if you have more than just a few objects to delete, due to the number of roundtrips to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly old post, but still actual.

If your table is very large (millions of entries), iterating using findall()*.delete() might not be the best option, as you can run into transaction timeouts (e.g. MySQL innodb_lock_wait_timeout setting) besides potential memory problems stated by GreenGiant.

So at least for MySQL Innodb, much faster is to use TRUNCATE TABLE:

```
sessionFactory.currentSession
  .createSQLQuery("truncate table ${sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(MyDomainClass).tableName}")
  .executeUpdate()
```

This is only useful if your table is not referenced by other objects as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

From what I learnt, I agree with @ataylor the below code is fastest IF there are no associations in your domain object (Highly unlikely in any real application):

```
DomainClass.executeUpdate('delete from DomainClass')
```

But if you have assiciations with other domains, then the safest way to delete (and also a bit slower than the one mentioned above) would be the following:

```
def domainObjects = DomainClass.findAll()
domainObjects.each { 
it.delete(flush:it==domainObjects.last, failOnError:true) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a list of objects and want to delete all elements, you can use `*` operator.

```
'*' will split the list and pass its elements as separate arguments.
```

Example.

```
List<Book> books = Book.findAllByTitle('grails')
books*.delete()
```